# Present/show list items in vertical view

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, xslt

I am using SharePoint 2013.

SharePoint list has 20+ columns but only two items. And only two items will be in future, items will not be changed or edited.

I want to show/present that list items in vertical view, as items will be columns and columns will be rows. So I would have 20+ rows and only three columns (item names plus two items).

It would be best if I could somehow make Preview pane to show both items at the same time, not just one at the moment as it is OOTB.

I read somewhere that something similar can be achieved with XSLT but I didn't find any good topic but there is no explanation just mentioning.

Option to create 20+ items instead of columns and only two columns (as items) is not an option.

I can use SP designer 2013, but don't have Visual Studio.

Comment: Why can't you create a table with the information instead of the list? 

Or if you really want the information in a list, you could use a Data View Web Part in SharePoint Designer and modify it with XSLT.

Comment: Where can I create it? Can you please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by creating sharepoint designer 2013 workflow. firstly I created two lists, one is original that has 100 columns and 2 rows (items) and the other has 2 columns and 100 items.

WF works like this:

I copied data from first and second rows to two dictionaries. every column represents one value in dictionary, I named them as 1 to 100 (as number of columns), difference between these two is only that 1st takes data from 1st item and 2nd takes data from 2nd item. After this I put a loop for 100 times for 100 items in my 2nd list (destination list). than in it i created parameters or body dictionary that has two values (names of columns from 2nd list). called rest api function POST and put increment at the end of loop so each time number will rise until it gets to 100. after this loop finishes and that's pretty much the end of job.

EDIT:
I am sure this could be done much easier but as I said I never worked with xslt and I don't have visual studio, I had to find solution the other/longer way.